# How does locking tables work?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a `php` script that will be requested several times "at the same time" I also have a field in a table let's call it `persons` as a flag for active/inactive. I want when the first instance of the script runs to set that field to inactive so that the rest instances will die when they check that field. Can someone provide a solution for that? How can I ensure that this script will run only once?

`PHP, PDO, MySQL`

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What storage engine are you using?

Comment: @eggyal: The storage engine is InnoDB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script should fetch the current flag within a transaction using a locking read, such as [`SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/innodb-locking-reads.html):

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE);

$dbh->beginTransaction();

// using SELECT ... FOR UPDATE, MySQL will hold all other connections
// at this point until the lock is released
$qry = $dbh->query('SELECT persons FROM my_table WHERE ... FOR UPDATE');

if ($qry->fetchColumn() == 'active') {
  $dbh->query('UPDATE my_table SET persons = "inactive" WHERE ...');
  $dbh->commit();  // releases lock so others can see they are inactive

  // we are the only active connection
} else {
  $dbh->rollBack();
  // we are inactive
}
```

Comment: I'm going more for this, but is it better than @Marc B's solution?

Comment: Well, This is not about scaleability, this will stay as it is, but the cleaner the better, and you gave sample code, so... I'm going for this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You can use MySQL's own 'named' locking functions without ever having to lock a table: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock

e.g. try `get_lock('got here first', 0)` with a 0 timeout. if you get a lock, you're first in the gate, and any subsequent requests will NOT get the lock and immediately abort.

however, be careful with this stuff. if you don't clean up after  yourself and the client which gained the lock terminates abnormally, the lock will not be released and your "need locks for this" system is dead in the water until you manually clear the lock.

Comment: The last bit here is incorrect. Dropping a MySQL connection automatically drops all locks it held.

Comment: true, but some people do use persistent connections.